# Boost smart pointers: Can I express it in a more concise way?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

today I've been working with Boost::shared_ptr, and I have a question.

```
vector<shared_ptr<KlasaA> > vec;
vec.push_back(shared_ptr<KlasaA>(new KlasaB));
vec.push_back(shared_ptr<KlasaA>(new KlasaC));
vec.push_back(shared_ptr<KlasaA>(new KlasaC));
vec.push_back(shared_ptr<KlasaA>(new KlasaA));

for (vector<shared_ptr<KlasaA> >::const_iterator c_it = vec.begin();
    c_it != vec.end(); ++c_it)
{
    cout << c_it->get()->foo(10) << endl;
}
```

The loop above goes through a vector and polymorphically invokes `foo(10)`.

My question is:

Can...

```
for (vector<shared_ptr<KlasaA> >::const_iterator c_it = vec.begin();
    c_it != vec.end(); ++c_it)
```

and

```
cout << c_it->get()->foo(10) << endl;
```

be expressed in a more concise way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Boost.Foreach`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/foreach.html) library. Then it will look pretty concise and clear:

```
BOOST_FOREACH( boost::shared_ptr<KlasaA> v, vec )
{
    std::cout << v->foo(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is a fine solution, but I personally don't like calling that variable 'it' as it is not an iterator in the c++ std library sense.

Comment: I chose this answer because I didn't know that Boost offers such a nice FOREACH. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<KlasaA> SharedKlasaA;
typedef vector<SharedKlasaA> KlasaAVector;

KlasaAVector vec;
vec.push_back(SharedKlasaA(new KlasaB));
...
for (KlasaAVector::const_iterator ...

cout << (*c_it)->foo(10);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your iterator initialization seems about as compact as can be, as far as I can see. If you really want to, you could write the loop function as:

```
cout << (*c_it)->foo(10) << endl;
```

This saves only 4 characters, but it does look a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

`shared_ptr` has an implicit downcast constructor, so you can write

```
vec.push_back(shared_ptr<KlasaB>(new KlasaB));
```

Notice the `shared_ptr` type is `shared_ptr<KlasaB>` and vec expects `shared_ptr<KlasaA>`.

With this in mind, you can replace `shared_ptr` constructor with `make_shared` function call (which may actually be preferred, anyway).

```
vec.push_back(make_shared<KlasaB>());
```

This will save you the hassle of typing in a bunch of class names.  `make_shared` accepts arguments which it will forward, so `make_shared<X>` is a nice replacement for `new X`.

You may notice that there are potential performance implications here: the `make_shared` data structure can (will?) be different, and there is an extra implicit conversion, but that may be optimized away by the compiler.  Profile and check.

Answer (score 0):

Dependently on compiler you may do such things:

```
std::foreach(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[](const boost::shared_ptr<KlasaA> &p){
  cout<<p->foo(10);
});
```

Comment: if you are using c++0x you may as well do range based for loop -- for( auto const & p : vec ) {}

Comment: Cool... Do you know anything about its presence in Standard? Haven't it been removed together with concepts?

Comment: It is still in the standard, though I see your concern about how it was defined before.  I don't know for certain how it is defined now, so I won't comment.